# Is this type aliasing syntax n Go?

Tags: go

I did not get the below syntax in `../go/src/net/http/server.go`:

```
var defaultServeMux ServeMux
```

where

`ServeMux` is a struct

```
type ServeMux struct {
    mu    sync.RWMutex
    m    map[string]muxEntry
    es    []muxEntry
    hosts    bool
}
```

---

In GO, type aliasing looks like `type T1 = T2`.

Is the above syntax(used for `defaultServeMux`) anything to do with type aliasing?

Comment: "Is the above syntax(used for defaultServeMux) anything to do with type aliasing?" - no.

Comment: The documentation and examples for type alias declarations are right at the top of the ["Type Declarations" section of the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations)

Comment: @JimB  yes  `var i int`

Comment: @overexchange: I'm not sure what that comment is responding to, but a _type_ declaration cannot start with `var`. The Keyword `var` isn't printed anywhere in the "Type Declarations" section.

Comment: @JimB Am saying that `var defaultServeMux ServeMux` is a variable declaration

Comment: Basic syntac questions are answered within the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org) which only takes a few minutes to finish.

Answer (score 5):

The line you quoted is just the declaration of a variable of type `ServeMux` which is the alternative, explicit variant of definition by assignment. For example these two statements are equivalent:

```
var foo ServeMux = ServeMux{}
foo := ServeMux{}
```

In both cases `foo` has the type `ServeMux`.

You can read about the variable declaration syntax [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables).
In the global variable scope the `:=` shorthand is not allowed which is why the `var` syntax is used to define global variables (as is the case in your example).

Type "aliases", i.e. the declaration of new types based on existing types has a [different syntax](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations) and has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Type aliasing is a relative [new addition](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#language) to the go language (mid-2017)